# Which plugins (javascript features) does babel-preset-env support?

Tags: babeljs, babel-preset-env

Babel-preset-env converts ES2015+ javascript features to compatible code for specified target environments.

But I checked https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env and https://babeljs.io/docs/en/presets, and it doesn't say there which javascript features are supported. It just says stage-x features are not supported.

Is it obvious which Ecmascript releases babel-preset-env supports? Maybe all the way up to ES2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only information I managed to find about this is in the [package.json](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-env/package.json) file of `@babel/preset-env`. Simply check out the list of dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I thought about something like that. It is an option, but the match with ECMA releases, and a note in their documentation would be very useful. I'll probably open an issue on their github, if I havent done that already.

Comment: Completely agree. I was searching for this information for my own needs, but I only found this stack overflow question :P

Answer (score -1):

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_versions.asp

All syntax and  (features of latest javascript, ES6 now)

Comment: Thanks. But this is not related to babel preset env.